# Laravel 5 - Redirect To URL After Registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

have multiple users with totally different post login panels. One for teachers and other for students. I made middlewares to separate their views. Middleware checks if a property ( column in database ) named entity is 'student' or 'company' and restricts or permits views accordingly. And yes Guest isnt permitted to either of the post login panel.

I am using same table to save logins. (entity column differentiates if its a teacher or student). Now I want to redirect the users to different views. If I alter `$redirectTo = "/studentPanel"`. Middleware acts and teacher login cannot access this . But if I hard code `$redirectTo = "/teacherPanel"` , then student post login panel is not accesible.

How can set `$redirectTo` dynamically . I thought of setting in construct method of auth controller.

Tried this:

```
public function __construct(Request $request ) {

$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);

if(Auth::user() && $request->user()->isStudent() )
    $this->redirectTo = "/studentPanel";
elseif(Auth::user() && $request->user()->isTeacher() )
    $this->redirectTo = "/teacherPanel";
else
      $this->redirectTo = "/auth/login";
```

}

Here `isStudent()` and isCompany are functions in App\User which respond with true or false checking the entity column value in Database.

I thought this way and I am getting error `"Call to a member function isStudent() on a non-object"`

Comment: `$request->user()` is not valid as the error says - take a look at the [Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: thanks let me check @ash and one thing is that my idea is correct to route dynamically? it will work?

Comment: it is not correct, I have an idea I will post an answer look at it and let me know,

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ okay

Comment: @CharlesMichel I am happy you solved your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `$request->user()` to `Auth::user()`.

From there, I have faced a very similar issue and the best solution I found at the time was to set `$redirectTo` to a static value, and in the route you find whether the user is a student or teacher and redirect appropriately.

The route would look like this:

```
public function getRedirect()
{

    if (Auth::user() && Auth->user()->isStudent()) {
        return redirect("/studentPanel");
    } else if(Auth::user() && Auth->user()->isTeacher()) {
        return redirect("/teacherPanel");
    } else {
        return redirect("/auth/login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the redirect in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DataCollector/RouterDataCollector.php in this file?

Comment: I wouldn't touch any of the files in vendor unless there was no other option. I imagined this method going in your controller, and creating a URL like `/controller/redirect` that you could set as the value of `$redirectTo`